# Inequalities in Python to check character's ordinal number

Tags: python, function, inequality

Is there a difference in writing something like `33 <= cp <= 47` vs `cp >= 33 and cp <= 47`?

More specifically, if there's a function that does:

```
def _is_punctuation(char):
  """Checks whether `chars` is a punctuation character."""
  cp = ord(char)
  if ((cp >= 33 and cp <= 47) or (cp >= 58 and cp <= 64) or
      (cp >= 91 and cp <= 96) or (cp >= 123 and cp <= 126)):
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

is it the same as:

```
def is_punctuation(char):
    """Checks whether `chars` is a punctuation character."""
    # Treat all non-letter/number ASCII as punctuation.
    # Characters such as "^", "$", and "`" are not in the Unicode
    # punctuation class but treat them as punctuation anyways, for consistency.
    cp = ord(char)
    if (33 <= cp <= 47) or (58 <= cp <= 64) or (91 <= cp <= 96) or (123 <= cp <= 126):
        return True
    return False
```

**Are there reasons to prefer `_is_punctuation()` over `is_punctuation()` or vice versa?**

**Would one be computationally faster than the other?** If so, how could we verify that? Using `dis.dis`?

---

P/S: I'm asking the question because I couldn't find a reason why would Google AI engineers prefer the original `_is_punctuation` implementation on https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/tokenization.py#L386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are semantically the same. You can also return the condition instead of using an if clause as it will evaluate to a boolean anyway:

```
return (33 <= cp <= 47) or (58 <= cp <= 64) or (91 <= cp <= 96) or (123 <= cp <= 126)
```

They (Google AI engineers) may not have known about chained comparisons or they [wanted it to perform *slightly* better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375753/why-are-chained-operator-expressions-slower-than-their-expanded-equivalent).