# How to do AND instead of OR in if statement comparing columns in PyQt5

Tags: python, if-statement, pyqt5, multiple-columns, qtablewidget

I have sample data structure like below:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | name_x | 14 | 15 | 16 | name_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | Brak | CD | CD | CD | Brak |
| CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | CD | Brak |

If I use statement as below it means to check if "Brak" string is in column 13 OR column 17. And that is a problem because i cannot execute further functions. How can I rewrite the code below to be used to check if string "Brak" is simultaneously  in column 13 and  column 17 in any row data.

I am using `QTableWidget` and `Sqlite` database.

```
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(r'Baza Danych/zestawienie.db')
        self.c = self.connection.cursor()

        query = "SELECT  * FROM Zestawienie"
        result = self.connection.execute(query)

        self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.setRowCount(0)
        for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
            self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.insertRow(row_number)
            for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
                self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.setItem(row_number, column_number,QTableWidgetItem(str(data)))

                if column_number in(13,17) :

                        if  "Brak"  in data:

                            break
                    
                        else:
                            for i in range(self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.columnCount()):
                                for j in range(self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.rowCount()):


                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

                                    img = r"IKONY\letter_k.png"
                                    img2 = r"IKONY\warning.png"

                                    lb = CustomWidget(str(i)+str(j), img)
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout.addStretch(1)
                                    lb2 = CustomWidget(str(i)+str(j), img2)



                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout.addWidget(lb)
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout.addWidget(lb2)

                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.cellWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.cellWidget.setLayout(self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout)
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.layout.setSpacing(0)
                                    
                                    self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.setCellWidget(row_number, 1,  self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.cellWidget)
```

Comment: @jarmod That would cause the checking for *every* column in the inner loop, while the condition could be placed outside of it.

Comment: Surely it would be much more efficient to let the db do the filtering: i.e. `SELECT * FROM Zestawienie WHERE name_x != 'Brak' AND name_y != 'Brak'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the check when you're looping over rows, not when you loop over columns.

```
for row_number, row_data in enumerate(result):
    if row_data[13] == 'Brak' and row_data[17] == 'Brak':
        self.ui.zestawienie_analiza_tab_2.insertRow(row_number)
        for column_number, data in enumerate(row_data):
            # rest of your code
```

Comment: What about `if row_data[13] == 'Brak' == row_data[17]`?

Comment: That works, too, I don't think it's as clear

Comment: Yeah, I thought the same. It probably all depends on the performance requirements. In theory, they are almost equivalent, but maybe in some situations (for thousands of records) there could be some margin of improvement.

Comment: @musicamante I just disassembled the two codes, it looks like the `and` version is a few less instructions. Which surprised me, I think they should be compiled identically.

Comment: See [Why are chained operator expressions slower than their expanded equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48375753/why-are-chained-operator-expressions-slower-than-their-expanded-equivalent) @musicamante

Comment: Oh, gosh, thank you for that: I did try to find resources on the topic, but it was hard to find the right keywords. I did some basic `timeit` tests and indeed found out some inconsistent results: I initially thought they were caused by caching, but something didn't add up. I also tried `ast.parse()`, which actually returned a "simpler" (and shorter) resolution for `a == b == c` version against `a == b and a == c`, so it *is* surprising. From the look of it, it almost seems like the implementation was *specifically* done for the benefit of the readability (so, *typically pythonic*).